# Problems comparing strings within an iterator

Tags: string, jsp, testing, struts2, iterator

I have problems comparing strings within an iterator
JSP:

```
<s:iterator value="piecesTxt">
   <s:if test="top.equals('_')">
      <s:textfield name="solIntrod" theme="simple" size="2" maxlength="1"/>
   </s:if>
   <s:else>
      <s:property/>
   </s:else>
 </s:iterator>
```

piecesTxt is a List that contains:
 - Pieces of text.
 - Gaps, storing in List the String "_"

JSP displays "_" as text:

```
El ot _ o d _ a f _ imos a na _ egar en un _ ate.
```

I've tried also with:

```
<s:if test="top == '_'">
Including in s:iterator var="pt"
<s:if test="pt == '_'"> 
<s:if test="pt.top == '_'">
<s:if test="pt.charAt(0) == '_'">
```

Other iterator-text works but this does not. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OGNL interprets a single character within single quotes as a `char`, not a `String`.

Use double-quotes:

```
<s:if test='top.equals("_")'>
```

See [Why won't the 'if' tag evaluate a one char string](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/why-wont-the-if-tag-evaluate-a-one-char-string.html) for details.

Comment: It works! Thanks!

I always use simple cuotes and works too:

     <s:if test="final.equals('NO')">

     <s:if test="#myObj.correct.equals('OK')">

Probably because the String containing at least two characters (?)